# Unit Testing JDBC when the app accesses different environments

Tags: java, unit-testing, jdbc, junit

I am needing help unit testing my utility. It is to be used as an internal utility that performs CRUD operations for two different apps that use SQL Databases. The utility is able to switch between any environment for the applications (DEV, INT, PERF, STAGE, or PROD) and perform operations against each. This is not a typical application where you specify the one environment at run time, the utility needs to access all environments while running.

So in order for the unit tests to have good coverage they need to test things on each environment (Some environments have different behavior).

Normally if I was testing JDBC stuff I would create a local copy of my Dev database and run my tests against that. But since there are two applications each with a DEV, INT, PERF, STAGE, and PROD environment I would need to create 10 local databases. This option seems like it could become pretty messy, and my fellow developers would probably not be too happy about having to do that much database setup just to get the tests to run.

Running the unit tests against the live versions of the database is absolutely not an option as any dummy data has the potential to crash multiple systems.

I was looking into several different mocking frameworks but was having trouble finding something that would play nicely with JDBC or not require an excessive amount of setup.

So my question is: are there any good frameworks for accomplishing this, or has anyone found a solution for a similar situation?

Comment: What are you trying to mock out?  One thing to consider is using a java memory database like H2 which is great for mocking out SQL data.  Your code needs to be database agnostic although H2 does a good job of simulating mysql.

Comment: If your tests are environment specific, then they are not unit tests, they are either integration tests, functional tests or acceptance tests, but definitely not unit tests.

Comment: I get what you are saying Mark, maybe I worded it poorly. Lets look at one example. So I have a single method that loops through a group of database connections (the different environments) and runs a select statement on each for a single record printing out the results to the user. Wouldn't testing that method be considered a unit test?

Comment: What do you want to test? Do you want to test your sql-statements? Then use a inmemory-database and test it (one test is enough since you would have to use a inmemory-database for every environment). If you want to test the configuration for your prod database without using it - I'm sorry, that's not possible within a junit test.

Answer (score 0):

> This option seems like it could become pretty messy, and my fellow developers would probably not be too happy about having to do that much database setup just to get the tests to run.

I don't think it has to become messy. Just be sure to make everything automated, scripted, environment independent (i.e. it should work on dev machines just as well as on your CI/CD pipeline). The perfect utility for you is [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org)

> Running the unit tests against the live versions of the database is absolutely not an option as any dummy data has the potential to crash multiple systems.

Yes, never do that! Not only will you crash your database, but worse (in my opinion), you will corrupt live data. Integration tests should always run on "throwaway databases"

> I was looking into several different mocking frameworks but was having trouble finding something that would play nicely with JDBC or not require an excessive amount of setup.

The excessive amount of setup to mock JDBC [could be solved with jOOQ](https://blog.jooq.org/easy-mocking-of-your-database/), which allows for mocking most of JDBC via a simple lambda (disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ). But I really recommend you don't go down that path, which only leads to pain and suffering. Instead of mocking / unit testing your database interaction, do run integration tests instead (again, using testcontainers).

This used to be very hard 20 years ago, but today, is super simple.